# How can I enable SQLLogger for doctrine2 in Zf2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

There is SQLLogger at Doctrine": http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/configuration.html#sql-logger-optional

But I don't know how can I use it in zf2. I want to see it in log-file. Not on website.

Thank you

Comment: *The logger class must implement the Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\SQLLogger interface. A simple default implementation that logs to the standard output using echo and var_dump can be found at Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger.* It's right there in the documentation, what's the problem? Did you even check the EchoSQLLogger file?

Comment: Thanks. my problem is, where can I set the config in zf2. yesterday did I find it. I set in autoloader of doctriner, also in array. I am PHP-Newbie. Now it is solved.

Comment: Good tutorial: http://erichutson.com/creating-a-quick-sql-logger-for-zf2-and-doctrine/